# Nested loops in R multiple replacement length

Tags: r, nested-loops

I am trying to create a loop that would generate the following:

```
[1] 1 1
[2] 1 2
[3] 1 3
[4] 2 1
[5] 2 2
[6] 2 3
[7] 3 1
[8] 3 2
[9] 3 3
```

Using the following code:

```
b<-list()
for (k in 1:9){
  for (i in 1:3) {
    for (j in 1:3){
      b[k]<- c(i,j)
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: use `[[` instead of `[` i.e b[[k]] not b[k]. (but yes, no need to loop here, and maybe a matrix would be better here than a list but your choice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a cross join of 1:3 with 1:3

```
data.table::CJ(1:3, 1:3)
```

But, if you wanted to use a loop you could do

```
b <- list()
k <- 0
for (i in 1:3) {
    for (j in 1:3){
      k    <- k + 1
      b[[k]] <- c(i,j)
    }
}
b
```

Comment: Thank you, I needed the loop solution because it was just a synthetic example of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of structure you would like to return, but you can do this very easily without expensive looping by using `cbind()` and R's convenient recycling feature.  This returns a matrix, which is the most appropriate structure for numerical data.

```
cbind(rep(1:3, each=3), 1:3)
 #      [,1] [,2]
 # [1,]    1    1
 # [2,]    1    2
 # [3,]    1    3
 # [4,]    2    1
 # [5,]    2    2
 # [6,]    2    3
 # [7,]    3    1
 # [8,]    3    2
 # [9,]    3    3
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to have data frame as outpout, you can use `expand.grid`:

```
expand.grid(1:3,1:3)
```

There seems to be no easy way to control which variable is moving faster, so if you need it to be the second, you can do:

```
expand.grid(1:3,1:3)[,2:1]

#    Var2 Var1
#  1    1    1
#  2    1    2
#  3    1    3
#  4    2    1
#  5    2    2
#  6    2    3
#  7    3    1
#  8    3    2
#  9    3    3
```